# start Nester Fragment without UI before android 4.2

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments. NoUIFragment has no UI. I want to start it from inside GreatFragment. How do I do that for API 14? For `4.2` instructions are [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compatibility (support) library. It supports nested fragments now: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html so you can have fragments support even on API8.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found it. I came to say so and found your answer. thanks.